# Need help encoding a huffman tree

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, huffman-code

Iv'e been trying to encode a Huffman tree, but I can't figure out why the Binary keys I get are all wrong. The tree is done correctly, so it's got to be an issue with my Binary Keys method.

Here's the code I'm using for encoding:

```
void Tree::CreateBinary(Node *r)
{
    if(r==nullptr)
    {
        cout << "empty Tree" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (r->character != NULL)
        {
            Binary(root, "", r->character);
        }

        CreateBinary(r->LeftSon);
        CreateBinary(r->RightSon);
    }

}

void Tree::Binary(Node *r, string key, char character)
{   

    if (r->LeftSon == NULL && r->RightSon == NULL && r->character == character)
    {
        r->key = key;
        cout << r->character << ": " << r->key << endl;
    }

    if (r->LeftSon != NULL)
    {
        if(r->LeftSon->character!=NULL && r->LeftSon->character!=character)
        {
            Binary(r->LeftSon, key, character);
        }else
        {
            key = key + "0";
            Binario(r->LeftSon, key, character);
        }

    }
    if (r->RightSon != NULL)
    {
        key = key + "1";
        Binary(r->RightSon, key, character);
    }

}
```

I've been using this tree as example:
[image: Huffman Tree]

and when I try to encode it I get these keys:

```
I: 00

P: 01

E: 010

A: 0110

T: 01110

SPACE: 011110

S: 011111
```

Comment: Your development environment almost certainly came with a debugger. With the debugger you can control the execution of your program and inspect it's state--the variables. This allows you to step through the program, line by line if need be, and watch for where it goes off the rails.

Comment: @user4581301 sadly, I already did that. Apparently the issue is that a binary value is ALWAYS being asigned when traversing the tree. Everything goes bad with the E, because god knows why, he adds the code from going  through the left son, and then entering the right son... I have no idea what else to do at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what you do to `key` here:

```
if (r->LeftSon != NULL)
{
    if(r->LeftSon->character!=NULL && r->LeftSon->character!=character)
    {
        Binary(r->LeftSon, key, character);
    }else
    {
        key = key + "0";
        Binario(r->LeftSon, key, character);
    }

}
if (r->RightSon != NULL)
{
    key = key + "1";
    Binary(r->RightSon, key, character);
}
```

At the top of the tree, there is a left son whose character is null, so you append '0' to `key`, then explore the right sub-tree with that key.

A simple fix:

```
Binario(r->LeftSon, key+"0", character);
```

Comment: damn you're a genius! that fixed the issue (I also did the same with the rightSon)